# How to say "including" or "it follows" for schedules and holidays etc

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, phrases

How do you say something along the lines of "my class schedule follows the holidays of the year" or "my class schedule is dependent on the national calender, including holidays.

授業の定刻は国の休み日をついて is the best I can come up with for the first one. Not even sure if tsuku is the correct word.

I have no idea what dependent would be. よって？

Answer (score 1):

I would use カレンダー[通]{どお}り or [暦]{こよみ}[通]{どお}り, as in...

> 「私の(orうちの)学校のスケジュールは、カレンダー[通]{どお}りです。or [暦]{こよみ}[通]{どお}りです。」
>
> 「私の学校は、カレンダー通りに or 暦通りに休みがあります。」

Comment: と in [通]{とお}り is voiced due to [連濁]{れんだく}, as you may know..